# Suddenly Can Not Connect to APNS Sandbox Environment with PushSharp

Tags: apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

We stopped being able to connect to the feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com about two days ago right in the middle of testing.   I checked the certificate and it is valid.  I also ran the openssl troubleshooting commands... and it all appeared ok.  But we also can NOT doing any testing or work against the sandbox APNS.  We are getting the following error about a malformed message response when we try and create the SSLStream connection.  I have been scratching my head for a day now... thinking it was something on our end... so would really appreciate a response if others are able to test and connect to the sandbox APNS using PushSharp current version 2.1.2 ??

A call to SSPI failed, see Inner exception" Inner Exception -> "The message received was unexpected or badly formatted."

Comment: possible duplicate of [PushSharp Apple - The message received was unexpected or badly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115394/pushsharp-apple-the-message-received-was-unexpected-or-badly-formatted)

Answer (score 3):

We were having the same issue using the now deprecated APNS-Sharp library (ancestor to PushSharp). I submitted a pull request for APNS-Sharp that fixes the issue based on my tests.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23121258/3542341

and for the pull request: https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/pull/369/files

Comment: I spent over 3 hour trying to figure out what going one with my code. I should come here first. When can we except a fix for that ? (Thank you Phil)

Comment: Thank you so much to Philip for fixing this in PushSharp....

As they said... still not an official word from Apple about the change... and production is still working under SSL... but we are preparing for that change also.

https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/pull/369